Playwright test failing in headless mode due to Paypal button
I have a Playwright test that confirms an e-commerce site's checkout process works, which terminates in clicking a Paypal button, logging into Paypal, and clicking submit payment.
In headed mode, it can interact with the Paypal popup just fine, but in headless mode, the Paypal widget doesn't render at all, and therefore there's no button to click. I've confirmed this using Playwright's page.screenshot() method.
From what I've read, this is a common problem because Paypal doesn't know their customers write integration tests, and therefore they treat any headless usage as evil bots trying to hack their sandbox site.
Is there any known workaround?
I'm running my test as part of a Django test case and the relevant Playwright startup code looks like:
SHOW = bool(int(os.environ.get('SHOW', 0)))

class Tests(StaticLiveServerTestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        os.environ["DJANGO_ALLOW_ASYNC_UNSAFE"] = "true"
        super().setUpClass()

        cls.playwright = sync_playwright().start()
        cls.browser = cls.playwright.chromium.launch(headless=not SHOW)

I've tried passing in "--disable-web-security", "--use-gl=desktop", "--disable-features=IsolateOrigins", and "--disable-site-isolation-trials", to launch(args=[...]) but those either have no effect or break the Paypal widget even in headed mode.

Did you try adding a human user agent? Please share a [mcve]. Thanks.

@ggorlen It's Playwright. It's scripting a real web browser which has a "human user agent". If the user agent was the problem, I'd be getting the error in non-headless mode.

In Playwright, the default headless user agent basically says "I am a robot", and that's the first line of defense for your script being blocked or behaving differently when running headlessly. Running it headlessly right now, I get Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) HeadlessChrome/125.0.6422.26 Safari/537.36 (note the HeadlessChrome part), while running headfully, I get Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/125.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 (note the absence of HeadlessChrome).

Now, simply spoofing the UA isn't a guarantee you won't be blocked, it's just a first attempt to bypass the issue and works on a decent chunk of sites. Browser fingerprinting is complex and unique to each site, so there needs to be a runnable example with a concrete site in the question to be able to provide a guaranteed working answer. Without that, it's all speculation.
